# Connecting physics bodies with PhysicsJoint

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, chipmunk

Lately I realized that Chipmunk (am I right?) was integrated with >= Cocos2d-x 3.0. Now I am trying make use of it (I am using cocos2d-x 3.2).

So can you tell if it's possible to connect the bodies (PhysicsBody) with PhysicsJoint (eg. PhysicsJointSpring), but **with connection points being placed for example on the edge** of the body?

I saw the "Joints tests" from the package with library, but it looks like all of them (joints) are placed in the midlle of the body - you could say that anchor point is placed at Vec2(0.5f, 0.5f).

Test are here (PhysicsDemoJoints class):
https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/v3/tests/cpp-tests/Classes/PhysicsTest/PhysicsTest.cpp

Here is an example what I am talking about (two balls, left bottom corner):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZgJJZTS0aMM

I would appreciate any help! And give you an internet hight five as a gift!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases take a look at the [class reference](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.2alpha0/df/d51/classcocos2d_1_1_physics_joint_distance.html).

You'll find that joints can be created with constructors similar to this one:

```
static PhysicsJointDistance *   construct (PhysicsBody *a, PhysicsBody *b, const Vec2 &anchr1, const Vec2 &anchr2)
```

The two vectors are the joint anchor points. Unfortunately it's not documented what they are, but typically they'll be in world (scene) coordinates.

Comment: Sleeping I was! ;) Thanks for the answer, I didn't notice that method.
And that's the high five!
http://i223.photobucket.com/albums/dd145/BSP06XRU/Misc%20Pics/InternetHighFive_zpsa9260a11.png